# Min height of html body element

Tags: css

I am creating a web page using HTML CSS and js. I have implemented the media queries for different width and they work perfectly as planned.
The min-height clause doesn't hold true upon window resizing. Upon vertical resizing, the webpage is getting squished even though I have declared all the section min-height (in pixels) individually.

```
body {
   min-height: 750px,
   height: 100vh,
   display : grid,
  ........ 
}
```

Please help

Comment: Can you provide a codepen or more details about your current code for review? There are too many variables and ways to set this up. Without more details it will be hard to answer your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the `min-height` and also you need to use `;` instead of `,`:

```
body {
  min-height: 750px;
  display: grid;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. That helped. Using just min-height instead of height and min-height

Answer (score 2):

Your CSS code is wrong. Use `;` instead of `,`

```css
body {
   min-height: 750px;
   height: 100vh;
   display : grid;
  ........ 
}
```

Comment: Yeah it was a typo. I was typing from my phone so din observe that.

Answer (score 0):

I think your `CSS` syntax is incorrect, you're using `,` instead of `;` for line break.
Try using `;` when closing `CSS statements`.

```
body {
   min-height: 750px;
   height: 100vh;
   display : grid;
}
```

Comment: Yes. I mistyped that